# How to keep the state updated using React hooks and observable design pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, observable

Here is the link for [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-wilson-ksvqm?file=/src/CryptoPrice.jsx:0-623).

I am learning about observable design pattern. I am trying to display Bitcoin price updating but I am currently getting `price` as `undefined`. I have API being called and also created observable methods to `subscribe` and `notify`.

I have an observer being created as constructor from the observable and trying to update the price state from API. But the price is showing as undefined. Where am I going wrong ?

```
export function Observable() {
this.observers = []; //array of observer functions
}

Observable.prototype = {
subscribe: function (fn) {
this.observers.push(fn);
},
fire: function () {
 this.observers.forEach((fn) => {
   fn.call();
  });
 }
};

import React from "react";
import { getBitcoinPrice } from "./api";
import { Observable } from "./observable";

const CryptoPrice = () => {
const [price, setPrice] = React.useState(0);

React.useEffect(() => {
  const bitcoinObservable = new Observable();
  console.log({ bitcoinObservable });
  let livePrice = bitcoinObservable.subscribe(getBitcoinPrice);
  setPrice(livePrice);
  console.log({ livePrice });
  let newPrice = bitcoinObservable.fire();
  console.log({ newPrice });
}, [price]);

return (
  <>
    <h3>{price ? price : "undefined"}</h3>
  </>
 );
};

export default CryptoPrice;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues with the code. Let me start with the implementation of observable:

1. Fire does not pass down a value to the observers! They are only notified that "something has happened", but not what exactly - so the observers would never hear the actual `price`.
2. You defnitely need an `unsubscribe` method!

So:

```js
export function Observable() {
  this.observers = []; //array of observer functions
}

Observable.prototype = {
  subscribe: function (fn) {
    this.observers.push(fn);
  },
  unsubscribe: function (fn) {
    const index = this.observers.findIndex(fn);
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.observers.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },
  fire: function (x) {
    this.observers.forEach((fn) => {
      fn(x);
    });
  }
};
```

A few things with `getBitcoinPrice`:

1. `const data = await response.data;` is redundant. You `await` on promises and only `axios.get(url)` is a promise. After that, `response.data` is a real object, just use it. No harm done though, if you await on a non-promise, it just runs immediately.
2. I saw that the `data.ticker.price` is a string actually, so changed it to `+data.ticker.price` to become a number. Again no harm done in this app, but I think this is better in the context of a bigger app.

So:

```js
export const getBitcoinPrice = async () => {
  const url = `https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd`;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    console.log('[getBitcoinPrice]', response.data.ticker.price);
    return +response.data.ticker.price;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("[getBitcoinPrice] error: ", error);
  }
};
```

Now to the core, the `CryptoPrice` component. The following is one way of doing it, I am sure there are better. Anyway, I have split processing into 2 phases: one is the periodic fetching of the price and firing the observable. The other is actually observing the change and doing an effect (here updating the display). Note the use of the cleanup function of React's `useEffect` - never forget to release resources!

```js
const CryptoPrice = () => {
  const [price, setPrice] = React.useState(0);
  const [bitcoinObservable] = React.useState(() => new Observable());

  // this effect is responsible for triggering the price load periodically
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(async () => {
      const x = await getBitcoinPrice();
      bitcoinObservable.fire(x);
    }, 5000);
    // the cleanup function of the effect, never forget!!!
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [bitcoinObservable]);

  // this effect is responsible for the subscription
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handler = function(price) {
      console.log('[CryptoPrice]', price);
      setPrice(price);
    };
    bitcoinObservable.subscribe(handler);
    return () => {
      bitcoinObservable.unsubscribe(handler);
    };
  }, [bitcoinObservable]);

  return (
    <>
      <h3>{typeof price === 'number' ? price : "undefined"}</h3>
    </>
  );
};
```

Last thing, zero is falsey in Javascript, so `price ? price : 'undefined'` would yield undefined for the initial price of `0`. Hence the type check `typeof price === 'number' ? ... : ...`.

A couple of more things/pointers:

- I would prefer to have the "1st phase", i.e. the creation of the "bitcoin price observable" outside of the component, probably in a service. Separation of concerns mostly.
- If you use a state management infrastructure, such as Redux, the "service" above would be some kind of middleware.
- A very interesting generalization of promises and the observable pattern are [reactive streams](https://rxjs.dev/). May be hard to grasp at first, but they are very powerful in the long term.
- If you combine Redux + RxJS, checkout [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/).

Comment: Your answer has lot of info which I was not aware of. Thank you. But I have few questions

1. Why are we setting the state in this way ? I don't see setState here.
`const [bitcoinObservable] = React.useState(() => new Observable());`
2. By adding `+` symbol to `+data.ticker.price` how does it become a number ?
3. Are we using `setInterval` to simulate observable behaviour ? or this is how observables work in real too like call in some interval?
Shouldn't it be called only when there is a change ?

Comment: Thank you too. 1. This is standard, but less frequently used: I only care about the initial state, so I am throwing away the `..., setBitcoinObservable]` part of the array. And, using a function as an initializer, I make sure that only 1 observable will ever be created in the lifetime of this component - `setState` will not call the initializer function in subsequent renderings. I am doing this because I do not want to create an `Observable` just to throw it away on each rendering.

Comment: 2. This is a standard JS "trick" to convert a number-formatted string to an actual number. E.g. see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus). 3. I used `setInterval` because I assumed you wanted the price to refresh periodically. I assumed this because this is the reason for actually using an observable, to observe changes. An observable that never changes value would be a sad observable indeed :D

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. But isn't the observable already doing that like updating price whenever there is a change rather than needing to use setInterval explicitly ? or is it just for the UI to see new prices ?

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood :) The `useEffect` depends on the price and fetches a new price. "Depends" means that, whenever the `CryptoPrice` is rendered, React will compare the current price with the previous. If changed, it runs the body of `useEffect` again. The initial price is zero and the first time `getBitcoinPrice` returns it is non-zero. `useEffect` senses this change and triggers`getBitcoinPrice` again. If the second time the price remains the same (and it does), no further updates are triggered!

Comment: I got it now. Thank you @Nikos

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm guessing that you're intentionally building your own observable to learn somsething, instead of using a library like `rxjs`, so I'm gonna focus on why your current implementation doesn't work. For production usage, I would highly recommend to use a battle tested library for observables instead of building your own.

Now to your code.

#### 1. You've mixed up the subscription and the emission (`fire` in your case)

Right now, your Observable will execute every function passed to `subscribe`  if you call `fire`. But None of the observers will ever get the API result, because you don't pass it to `fire`. You should modify your observable like this:

```js
export function Observable() {
  this.observers = []; //array of observer functions
}

Observable.prototype = {
  subscribe: function (fn) {
    this.observers.push(fn);
  },
  // add parameter value
  fire: function (value) {
    this.observers.forEach((fn) => {
      // call the observer callbacks directly with value
      fn(value);
    });
  }
};
```

#### 2. You never "fire" your observable with the API result.

Instead, you've passed the Promise that returns the bitcoin price to the `subscribe` function. As said before, this way, no other observer could ever receive the API result.

You should modify your `useEffect` this way:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  const bitcoinObservable = new Observable();

  bitcoinObservable.subscribe((livePrice) => {
    console.log("sub!", { livePrice });
    setPrice(livePrice);
  });

  getBitcoinPrice().then((livePrice) => {
    console.log('fire!', { livePrice });
    bitcoinObservable.fire(livePrice);
  });
}, [])
```

Now your code sandbox example already works fine. Of course, creating the observable and subscribing to it within the same `useEffect` call doesn't make much sense. But if you want to use your observable in more than one place, there is some other thing you should do:

#### 3. Add unsubscribe logic to avoid memory leaks

React components get mounted and unmounted all the time, and the useEffect logic with them. If you don't unsubscribe from the observable, you could cause memory leaks. So you should add an unsubscribe function like this to your Observable:

```js
Observable.prototype = {
  subscribe: function (fn) {
    this.observers.push(fn);
    // return an object with the unsubscribe function
    return {
      unsubscribe: () => {
        this.observers.splice(this.observers.indexOf(fn));
      }
    };
  },
  // ...
};
```

Then in your `useEffect`, you can unsubscribe within the effects [cleanup callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1):

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  // ...
  // save the return object of the subscribe call
  const subscription = bitcoinObservable.subscribe((livePrice) => {
    console.log("sub!", { livePrice });
    setPrice(livePrice);
  });

  // ...

  // add cleanup logic
  return () => {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);
```

This will cleanup your subscription callbacks if the component gets destroyed. This will be necessary as soon as you use your observable in more place than one.

If you want to want to know more about observables, I recommend articles like this one: https://indepth.dev/posts/1155/build-your-own-observable-part-1-arrays

Comment: Thank you @maximillian for the answer